# Django CSS Not Loading

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates

I'm having problems with my Django > css its not loading on the page for some reason am I missing something ?

I have attached snippets of my current code

Settings.py
[image]

urls.py
[image]

.html
[image]

Comment: You need to add the static URLs, and furthermore it will only work with `DEBUG = True`.

Comment: See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put in you'r setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
    ]
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

STATIC_DIR
]
```

then create folder  static/file.css(nameyourfile.css)

and then put in your  ...html :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{% static "file.css" %}">


    {% load sataticfiles %}
```

if you use version 3. put :

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: TY! I just had to remove the STATIC_URL and replace it with 

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

STATIC_DIR
]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a few more things to configure your static files.

First, you need to make sure **django.contrib.staticfiles** is included in your [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) in your django settings.

Also, you need to add this line in your html document:

```
{% load static %}
```

I would follow this guide which explains static files in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files).